# Tail Recursion, why it's efficent?

Tags: c++, algorithm, function, recursion, tail-recursion

I was watching: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_JtPhF8MshA

Where the following implementation:

```
int factorial (int n)
{
    if (n==0) return 1;
    return n * factorial(n-1);
}
```

with the following:

```
int factorial (int n)
{
    return go(n, );
}

int go(int n, int a)
{
    if (n==0) return a;
    return go(n-1, a*n);
}
```

Where he claimed the second is more efficient but my question is why?

Both call the function exactly the same number of times, thus 2 of them are O(n).

Comment: Because the first of deep down `n` time deeper than the second one in the "Stack‌" memory.

Comment: Tail recursion doesn't actually call the function, instead it reuses the call-stack frame and just jumps to the start of the function. The stack reuse allows very deep recursion, and a plain jump is more effective than a call.

Comment: This is another good answer, specific to the code you wrote and C: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization/9814654#9814654

Comment: @OmG so in the first we are using O(n) memory while in the other O(1)?